# Drawing triangles using a circle

Tags: ios, ipad, drawing, uibezierpath

Is there a way to let users draw a triangle using a circle (transparent circle) in iOS. I was thinking setting three equal points in the circle to create the triangle and as it stretch the circle the triangle gets build. Maybe using bezierPathWithArcCenter or bezierPathWithOvalInRect. Anyone ever done this?

Comment: You want to draw a triangle given its incircle?

Comment: have a circle and the triangle inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already got gesture recognizers or some other system in place for capturing the location of the user's touches, doing the drawing itself is straightforward.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Draw circle
CGFloat derivedRadius = self.radius * self.scale;
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(self.center.x - derivedRadius, self.center.y - derivedRadius);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, derivedRadius * 2, derivedRadius * 2));

// Draw triangle
CGFloat t1 = self.rotation;
CGFloat t2 = self.rotation + ((2 * M_PI) / 3);
CGFloat t3 = self.rotation + ((4 * M_PI) / 3);
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(self.center.x + cosf(t1) * derivedRadius, self.center.y + sinf(t1) * derivedRadius);
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(self.center.x + cosf(t2) * derivedRadius, self.center.y + sinf(t2) * derivedRadius);
CGPoint p3 = CGPointMake(self.center.x + cosf(t3) * derivedRadius, self.center.y + sinf(t3) * derivedRadius);
CGPoint endpoints[] = { p1, p2, p3, p1 };
CGContextAddLines(context, endpoints, 4);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Where `self.radius`, `self.scale`, `self.center`, and `self.rotation` are properties that capture the result of the user's gestures. Rotation should be in radians.